# Map rotation according to origin of stage kineticJS

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I 'm working on a navigation project.I have a map like this.

[image]

I need to rotate this map according to the green point which is on [400,300] px on the stage.I tried a lot of things but it did not work.Here is my rotate function.

```
function rotateMap(layer, t_angle) {

layer.setOffset(400, 300);
layer.rotateDeg(t_angle);
layer.draw();
layer.move(400, 300);
};
```

This rotates map only one time.When i tried to use it in a timer event,the map doesn't appears after first rotation.Is there any efficial way to do this rotation?

**EDIT : I have 2 layers in my stage that one of for lines and the other one for the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Instead of offsetting the layer, put the lines in a group and rotate the group.**

I’m assuming your full screen is 800x600 and you want to rotate around the center 400x300

*The Method*

- Put your lines on a group
- Set your group width x height to 800x600
- Set your group x/y to 400/300
- Set your group offset to 400,300
- To rotate, call group.rotateDeg(degrees)
- Be sure to layer.draw() after each rotation.

Example of your map-group:

```
    var map=new Kinetic.Group({
        x:400,
        y:300,
        width:800,
        height:600,
        offset:[400,300]
    });
    layer.add(map);
```

Example of your rotation function

```
    function rotateMap(t_angle) {
        map.rotateDeg(t_angle);
        layer.draw();
    };
```

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/wDxcT/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.7.0.min.js"></script>

<style>
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
}
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 400,
        height: 400
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);

    var t_angle=30;

    function rotateMap(t_angle) {
    map.rotateDeg(t_angle);
    layer.draw();
    };

    var map=new Kinetic.Group({
        x:200,
        y:200,
        width:200,
        height:200,
        offset:[100,100]
    });
    layer.add(map);

        var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            width: 200,
            height: 200,
            fill: 'skyblue',
            stroke: 'lightgray',
            strokeWidth: 3
        });
        map.add(rect);
        var north = new Kinetic.Text({
            x: map.getWidth()/2-15,
            y: 25,
            text: 'N',
            fontSize: 42,
            fontFamily: 'Calibri',
            fill: 'green'
        });
        map.add(north);



    var c=new Kinetic.Circle({
      x:200,
      y:200,
      radius:5,
      fill:"green"
    });
    layer.add(c);

    layer.draw();


    $("#rotate").click(function(){
        rotateMap(t_angle);
    });


}); // end $(function(){});

</script>       
</head>

<body>
    <button id="rotate">rotate</button>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yep,it worked.But when i call rotate function twice it rotates only one time.If i want to rotate the map 2 time in 90 degree,i need to call rotateMap function 90 degree first.For the second i need to call it with 180 degree.What's the reason of this?